# Windows 8 Store App Certification - Snapped View

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store

In the Windows 8 Store App certification requirements it states that your app must support a snapped view. Does anyone know if it's possible to create a single snapped view that persists across the app? For instance on my main view I have 4 buttons that take you to different parts of the app, the buttons do not exist on the other views. What the design team is requesting that I do is create a snap view with the four buttons and some default text describing the app, they want this to be the snapped view for each page.

1. Is that possible?
2. Will Windows accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes it is possible
2. Yes it will. I've seen several apps doing this including at least one of the first party apps. Store itself shows static image for snap view.